# Reading a CSV file of varying precision in Fortran

Tags: csv, fortran, gfortran, data-analysis, fortran95

I am using an external program to run a simulation which returns to me a csv file containing output data. I need to read the data from this file into my fortran program, which analyses and optimizes the input conditions to rerun the external program.

The CSV file has say 20 columns and 70 rows. Each column contains output data for a specific parameter. Now since that program is not written by me, I cannot control the precision of the output values. So in many cases the external program truncates the number of digits after the decimal it they are zero. So it is possible in run number 1, a certain field has 3 digits after the decimal, but has only 2 digits after the decimal in run number 2.

What am I supposed to do for this? I cannot use the read command since in that I need to specify in advance the number of digits my program has to read.

I basically need a way for my program to identify data between commas and read a value or varying precision between the commas.

Comment: *I need to specify in advance the number of digits my program has to read*  Not always.  Try *list-directed* input, e.g. `read(unit,*) c1, c2, c3, ...`  That is, use `*` as the format for reading.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you have any error message or something? How does the code and the input file look like?

Comment: @Mark, Thanks... and yes Actually ended up doing that. Didn't want to for various reasons. But had to.. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

For input, the decimal part of a format specifier is only used **if the input field does not contain a decimal point**.

For the last few decades (since the demise of punched cards), users typically expect that a numeric value that doesn't contain a decimal point is an integer value.  Consequently,  **for input, format specifications for real numbers should always have `.0` for their decimal part**.

For example, after:

```
CHARACTER(4) :: input
REAL :: a, b
input = '1   '
READ (input, "(F4.0)") a
READ (input, "(F4.1)") b
```

`a` will have the value 1.0, and `b` will have the value 0.1.

(For input, it doesn't particularly matter which particular real data descriptor is used (F, E, D, or G) - they all behave the same regardless of the nature of the input.)

So, for input, all you have to worry about is getting the field width right.  Once you have read a record into a string this is easy enough to do by using the INDEX intrinsic.